# Update mysql columns with username

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

For example if i have a table structure like so and i want to update admin so how can i do that ?

```
+-----------+-----------+
|   sender  | recipient |
+-----------+-----------+
|   admin   | user1     |
|   user1   | admin     |
+-----------+-----------+
```

**What i have tried?**

```
UPDATE messages 
SET (sender='newname' OR recipient='newname') 
WHERE (sender='admin' OR recipient='admin')
```

ERROR:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '(sender='dsfdsx' OR recipient='dsfdsx') WHERE (sender='admin' OR
>   recipient='admi' at line 1

What should be changed?

Comment: i suppose you didn't put * near the select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional expressions `CASE..WHEN` to `UPDATE` accordingly:

```
UPDATE messages
SET 
  sender = CASE sender WHEN 'admin' THEN 'newname' ELSE sender END, 
  recipient = CASE recipient WHEN 'admin' THEN 'newname' ELSE recipient END
WHERE 
  sender = 'admin' OR recipient = 'admin'
```

Comment: Ah let me try this.

Comment: That indeed works thanks mate!I can accept this answer in 4 minutes from now on.